# How to integrate MBProgressHUD when loading a UIwebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mbprogresshud

I am a novice in ios development. I have integrate A UIWebView in my app to load a web page. This loading is done in viewdidLoad function.

I would like to integrate MBProgressHUD during the loading of the webpage.

Can you help me please? Do you have some examples?

Thanks for your help.

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) offers you three methods that you can use for that:

```
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

You can show the progress view in `webViewDidStartLoad:` and remove it in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` or `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`.

[Here](http://blog.elucidcode.com/2011/03/using-a-hud-to-display-alerts-in-ios/) you can find an example of showing/hiding MBProgressHUD.